# How can I specify validation only for one model with polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic model `command` who can be associated to a `cover` or to an `additional_return`.
Those are the field in `command` :

```
  create_table "commands", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "placement_date"
    t.date     "estimated_delivery_date"
    t.string   "commandable_type"
    t.integer  "commandable_id"
    ...
  end
```

The thing is : for `cover` I would like to validate the `estimated_delivery_date` but not for the model `additional_return`. How can I specify a validation only for one model ?

```
 class Command < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :commandable, polymorphic: true
   validates_presence_of :commandable_type,
                         :commandable_id
 end
```

Comment: can you try `validates : estimated_delivery_date, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |c| c.commandable_type == 'Cover' }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
validates :estimated_delivery_date, presence: true, if: :date_required?

private
def date_required?
  commandable.is_a?(Cover)
end
```